# How to give sections dynamically in horizontally List view in UWP?

Tags: listview, uwp, uwp-xaml, sections

I am New UWP. Using tutorial and some stack links I got the List view with section but I don't know how to add sections dynamically in list view.
I want section like below image,
[image: Section in Row]

Here I implemented some code in my XAML:

```
<Grid Background="White" Margin="20,20">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="back" Click="Back_Button" ClickMode="Press"   Content="back"
                 Padding="5 5 5 5"   FontSize="20" Foreground="Blue" Background="White" 
                 Grid.Row="0" />

        <ListView x:Name="channellistView" RelativePanel.Below="back"                 
                  RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChangedAsync"
                   Padding="5 5 5 5" Margin="5 25 5 5"  Grid.Row="1" 
                  >
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:FadeHeaderBehavior />
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Channelheader}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RelativePanel Background="White" Margin="5 5"                   
                        >

                        <Image  x:Name="tick" Source="{Binding TickImage}"
                                Width="30" Height="30" 
                                Margin="2 2"                              
                                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"                               
                    />

                        <Image  x:Name="channelImage" Source="{Binding ChannelPicture}"
                                Width="30" Height="30" 
                                Margin="2 2"                              
                               RelativePanel.RightOf="tick"
                                  RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                    />

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChannelName}" 
                           Margin="5 5 5 5"                         
                           FontSize="14" 
                           FontStyle="Normal"                     
                            Width="770"                    
                           Foreground="Black"  x:Name="channelnametext"                     
                           RelativePanel.RightOf="channelImage" 
                                   />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChannelDescription}" 
                           Margin="5 5 5 5"                         
                           FontSize="10" 
                           FontStyle="Normal"                     
                            Width="770"                    
                           Foreground="Black"  x:Name="channelnameDesc"                     
                           RelativePanel.RightOf="channelImage" 
                                   RelativePanel.Below="channelnametext"
                                   />
                        <Button  x:Name="info"    
                    Width="30" Height="30" ClickMode="Press" Click ="info_Button"
                    RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
         Margin="5 5 5 5" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" >
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="/Assets/info_icon_blue.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </RelativePanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.Header>
                <Grid x:Name="MyHeaderGrid" MinHeight="50" Height="50">
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Private Channel" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="Black" Margin="0,5" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Thanks, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question, your xaml clearly tells me you are adding the group template dynamically.

Comment: ok now how to add my group title dynamically. means in .xaml.cs file?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/PullToRefreshUWP_WindowsComposition). I am using a grouped listview there.

Comment: I want to know that how to add group header (dynamically) and listview values dynamically in C# UWP.